# UITableView gets resize only in ViewDidAppear

Tags: uitableview, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I got a weird problem and i don't know where/how to fix it...

i have 6 UITableViews on a UIViewController ( i'm using storyboard ), i would like to resize them in the ViewDidLoad but i cannot, the only way i found to resize them it is in the ViewDidAppear, the problem is when i rotate my simulator the frame become like in IB.

Could you please help me on this case ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_hoursTable setScrollEnabled:NO];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_firstTable setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 768)];
    [_secTable setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 100)];
    [_thirdTable setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 0, 100, 100)];
    [_fourthTable setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 0, 100, 100)];
    [_fifthTable setFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 100, 100)];
    [_hoursTable setFrame:CGRectMake(600, 0, 100, 100)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of code should be in `layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok now i get it, self.view is in ViewDidLoad and the subviews in layoutSubviews

Comment: doesnt change anything layoutSubviews doesn't get called .. my uitableviews are linked into IB.. does this change something ... ?

Comment: Is layoutSubviews getting called?

Comment: only if i add it to viewdidload

Comment: I updated my answer, make sure that you have the method implemented correctly, as it should be called.  Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html